# Как убрать лишнюю высоту у header, которая появляется с 992px?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

У меня такая проблема. Начина с разрешения в 992px, у header увеличивается высота и секция, которая находится под ним - уезжает вниз. Как это исправить? Подскажите, пожалуйста! Скрин прикрепляю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы лучше код свой приложите - в виде воспроизводимого примера. Скрин никак не поможет в решении Вашей проблемы.

Comment: добавил, указал место, на котором должен заканчиваться хедер

Comment: Ваш пример не воспроизводим, так как ни картинок ничего нету, а вообще, что мешает задать header элементарно фиксированную высоту?

Comment: или например `header{ max-height: ваше значение }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У блока "header-bg2", который находится справа внутри header изначально задана высота:

```css
.header-bg2 {
      min-height: 500px;
    }
```

Если вначале задали высоту "min-height", то для каждого разрешения экрана ее также нужно задать, только поменьше. 
А так получается что при разрешении экрана 992X450 вы высоту не указали, и у блока "header-bg2" осталась та же высота 500px, при этом вы еще задали верхний отступ:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 992px)
    .header-bg2 {
        width: 400px;
        margin-top: 180px;
    }
```

Поэтому header растягивается и его высота составляет около 700px. Измените высоту или верхний отступ блока "header-bg2"

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того, что ваш пример не воспроизводим должным образом, по-этому я выскажу свое мнение по поводу вашего вопроса.

У вас есть несколько вариантов решения вашей проблемы:

1. Использование JS кода (jQuery) - по сути тот же медизапрос :

   `var mql = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 992px)');
   if (mql.matches) {
      $(".header").css("height" , "ваше значение");
      $(".header-title").css("margin-top" , "30px");
   }`
2. Тот же медиа запрос в CSS

   `@media and screen (max-width: 992px){
   .header-title{
     margin-top: 30px;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .header-title {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
  .header-bg2 {
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 180px;
  }
```

при расширение 992px у вас margin-top: 180px; в  .header-bg2. Задайте margin-top: поменьше

Comment: Я так и не понял, у него проблема с тем когда сужение идет или расширение?

Comment: сужение. с 992 и ниже